# ZFS and FreeNAS: Mirror using half a drive

Tags: partitioning, raid, nas, freenas, zfs

I'm planning to set up a FreeNAS server with two of my spare drives:

- 1x 1TB drive
- 1x 2TB drive

Both drives are identical besides their capacity and neither has any data on it.

Is it possible to set up a RAID 1 mirror using all of the 1TB drive's capacity and half of the 2TB drive's capacity, leaving 1TB free on the 2TB drive to use as another volume? I would really like to have a mirror between the drives but don't want the 2TB drive's extra space to go to waste.

Any help would be greatly appreciated. Thanks!